# Tensorflow Initialise Variables

Tags: python, tensorflow

I just want to see my output so far but I can't get my variables to initialize, the same function to do that worked in another notebook but is not working in this one. I tried two ways and keep getting:

```
FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable.
```

I am using 1.2.1.

```
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('./', one_hot=True)

n1=500

n2=300

nclasses=10

batchsize=100

def layers(data):

    layer1={'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784,n1])),
                                  'bias':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n1]))}

    layer2={'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n1,n2])),
                                  'bias':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n2]))}
    output={'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n2,nclasses])),
                                  'bias':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([nclasses]))}

    l1=tf.add(tf.matmul(data,layer1['weights']),layer1['bias'])
    l1=tf.nn.relu(l1)

    l2=tf.add(tf.matmul(l1,layer2['weights']),layer2['bias'])
    l2=tf.nn.relu(l2)

    output=tf.add(tf.matmul(l2,output['weights']),output['bias'])

    return output

session=tf.Session().   

session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

result=session.run(layers(mnist.test.images))


print(type(result))
```

tried as well-

```
with tf.Session() as sess:

    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    result=sess.run(layers(mnist.test.images))

    print(type(result))
```

Comment: Why the dot after `session=tf.Session().` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the graph is constructed within the function call `layers`. But you initialized all variables **before** you construct your graph.

Hence, you need to write

```
output_op = layers(mnist.test.images)
session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
result = session.run(output_op)
```

op)

Then the graph is constructed and TensorFlow can initialize all variables. Full working example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def fake_mnist():
    return np.random.randn(1, 28 * 28)

n1 = 500
n2 = 300
nclasses = 10
batchsize = 100


def layers(data):

    layer1 = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, n1])),
              'bias': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n1]))}

    layer2 = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n1, n2])),
              'bias': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n2]))}
    output = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n2, nclasses])),
              'bias': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([nclasses]))}

    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, layer1['weights']), layer1['bias'])
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, layer2['weights']), layer2['bias'])
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

    output = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2, output['weights']), output['bias'])

    return output


with tf.Session() as sess:
    data_inpt = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    output_op = layers(data_inpt)

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    result = sess.run(output_op, {data_inpt: fake_mnist()})
    print(type(result))
    print(result)
```

I highly doubt, that *your* code is running in any another notebook file. I guess in the other notebook file you have executed the cell with `layers` multiple time such that in the second call of `tf.global_variables_initializer` the variables in the graph already exists. But the code you posted is definitely not correct.

Answer (score -1):

since you mentioned that the code works on another notebook, so it could be tf version issue, so instead of using `session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())`, try `session.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())`, btw tf.initialize_all_variables() is currently deprecated.